# Calculate the limit: $\lim_{x\to+\infty}(\frac{x^2 -x +1}{x^2})^{\frac{-3x^3}{2x^2-1}}$ without de l'Hôpital rule

Tags: limits, logarithms, limits-without-lhopital, indeterminate-forms

I was wondering how can I calculate the limit:

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(\frac{x^2 -x +1}{x^2}\right)^{\frac{-3x^3}{2x^2-1}}$$

without de l'Hôpital rule.

I tried to reconduct the limit at the well known one:

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x = e$$

Now I'm concentrating only on the part of the limit with still the Indeterminate Form, I reached this form elevating $e$ to the neperian logarithm of the function, trying to get rid of the $1^\infty$ I.F.

but, at the end of the day, I could only obtain:

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to+\infty}\ln\left(\frac{1}{x^2}(1+x^2-x)\right) &= \lim_{x\to+\infty} \ln\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) + \lim_{x\to+\infty} \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^2-x}}\right) \\&= \lim_{x\to+\infty} \ln\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) + \lim_{x\to+\infty} (x^2-x) \ln\left(\left(1 + \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^2-x}}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2-x}}\right)\end{align}$$

But then defining

$$t= \frac{1}{x^2-x}$$

the limit

$$\lim_{t\to 0}  \ln\left(\left(1 + \frac{1}{t}\right)^{t}\right)$$

goes no more to

$$ \ln(e)$$

because now $$t \to 0$$

Can you please give me some help?

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks! https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left(\frac{x^2 -x +1}{x^2}\right)^{\frac{-3x^3}{2x^2-1}}=\left(1+\frac{1-x}{x^2}\right)^{\frac{x^2}{1-x}\frac{-3x(1-x)}{2x^2-1}}=\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{1-x}}\right)^{\frac{x^2}{1-x}}\right]^{\frac{3x^2-3x}{2x^2-1}}\to e^\frac32$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left(\frac{x^2 -x +1}{x^2}\right)^{\frac{-3x^3}{2x^2-1}}=\exp\left[\frac{-3x^3}{2x^2-1}\ln\left(\frac{x^2 -x +1}{x^2}\right)\right]=\exp\left[\frac{-3x^3}{2x^2-1}\ln\left(1-\frac{x-1}{x^2}\right)\right]
$$
The exponent
$$
\left[\frac{-3x^3}{2x^2-1}\ln\left(1-\frac{x-1}{x^2}\right)\right]\sim-\frac{3}{2}x\left(-\frac{x-1}{x^2}\right)\to 3/2\ ,
$$
therefore the sought limit is $e^{3/2}$. The above asymptotic estimate is obtained using the Maclaurin expansion of $\ln$.

Answer (score 1):

If we Put $x=1/t$, the limit becomes
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+} (t^2-t+1)^\frac {-3}{t(2-t^2)} $$

Taking logarithm and using the fact that

$$\ln (1-t+t^2)\sim -t+t^2$$

we find that the limit of the logarithm is

$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac {-3}{t (2-t^2)}(-t+t^2)=\frac 32$$

the result is then $$e^\frac 32$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $e^x$ and $\ln$ are continuous functions, we obtain:
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(\frac{x^2 -x +1}{x^2}\right)^{\frac{-3x^3}{2x^2-1}}=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(1+\frac{x^2 -x +1}{x^2}-1\right)^{\frac{1}{\frac{x^2 -x +1}{x^2}-1}\cdot\left(\frac{x^2 -x +1}{x^2}-1\right)\frac{-3x^3}{2x^2-1}}=$$
$$=
\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(1+\frac{x^2 -x +1}{x^2}-1\right)^{\frac{1}{\frac{x^2 -x +1}{x^2}-1}\cdot\frac{3(x^2-x)}{2x^2-1}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}e^{\frac{3(x^2-x)}{2x^2-1}\cdot\ln\left(1+\frac{x^2 -x +1}{x^2}-1\right)^{\frac{1}{\frac{x^2 -x +1}{x^2}-1}}}=$$
$$=e^{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{3(x^2-x)}{2x^2-1}\cdot\ln\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\left(1+\frac{x^2 -x +1}{x^2}-1\right)^{\frac{1}{\frac{x^2 -x +1}{x^2}-1}}}=e^{\frac{3}{2}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

> **I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that uses only the squeeze theorem and elementary inequalities obtained using pre-calculus analysis.  To that end we proced.**

---

In [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263)
, I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that the logarithm function satisfies the inequalities

$$\frac{x-1}{x}\le \log(x)\le x-1\tag1$$

Using $(1)$, it is straightforward to see that

$$-\frac{x-1}{x^2-x+1}\le \log\left(1-\frac{x-1}{x^2}\right)\le -\frac{x-1}{x^2}\tag 2$$

Multiplying $(2)$ by $\displaystyle -\frac{3x^3}{2x^2-1}$ and inverting the inequality signs accordingly reveals

$$\begin{align}
\underbrace{\left(\frac{3x^3}{2x^2-1}\right)\,\left(\frac{x-1}{x^2}\right)}_{\displaystyle=\frac{3-3/x}{2-1/x^2}}\le -\frac{3x^3}{2x^2-1}\log\left(1-\frac{x-1}{x^2}\right)\le \underbrace{ \left(\frac{3x^3}{2x^2-1}\right)\,\left(\frac{x-1}{x^2-x+1}\right)}_{\displaystyle \frac{3-3/x}{(2-1/x^2)(1-1/x+1/x^2)}}\tag 3
\end{align}$$

Applying the squeeze theorem to $(3)$, we find that

$$\lim_{x\to \infty }\left(-\frac{3x^3}{2x^2-1}\log\left(1-\frac{x-1}{x^2}\right)\right)=\frac32$$

from which we find by virtue of the continuity of the exponential function that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{x^2-x+1}{x^2}\right)^{-\frac{3x^3}{2x^2-1}}&=\lim_{x\to \infty }e^{-\frac{3x^3}{2x^2-1}\log\left(1-\frac{x-1}{x^2}\right)}\\\\
&=e^{\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(-\frac{3x^3}{2x^2-1}\log\left(1-\frac{x-1}{x^2}\right)\right)}\\\\
&=e^{3/2}
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

> **Main Tools Used:  The Squeeze Theorem, Inequalities in $(1)$.**

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.